# Zend framework SQL select query construction (WHERE CLAUSE)

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I am trying to generate a query that selects all from a user table where any combination of the last name of first name matches a particular search term

```
$select = $select->where('last_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%')->orWhere('first_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere("CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%');
```

There is another condition that has to also has to be met which is specified in another where clause

```
$select = $select->where("deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0");
```

The Following SQL statement is generated

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE (last_name LIKE '%frank%') OR (first_name LIKE '%frank%') OR (CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE '%frank%') OR (CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE '%frank%') AND (deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0) ORDER BY `date_created` desc LIMIT 25
```

This doesnt return the desired result as i get rows where scholar = 1;

I figured the query should be

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE ((last_name LIKE '%frank%') OR (first_name LIKE '%frank%') OR (CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE '%frank%') OR (CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE '%frank%')) AND  (deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0) ORDER BY `date_created` DESC LIMIT 25
```

What the right syntax to achieve this using the $select object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use quoteInto to prepare your conditions and then use them like  this :

```
    $first_name_cond = $db->quoteInto('first_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%');
    $last_name_cond = $db->quoteInto('last_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%');

    $concat_cond1 = $db->quoteInto("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%');

    $concat_cond2 = $db->quoteInto("CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%');


    $select = $select->where($first_name_cond.' OR '.$last_name_cond.' OR '.

             $concat_cond1.' OR '.$concat_cond2)->where("deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume *deleted* and *scholar* are separate columns. So the easiest way is to just break:

```
$select = $select->where("deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0");
```

into two statements, like:

```
$select->where("deleted = ?", 0);
$select->where("scholar = ?", 0);
```

this change should result in a sql string like:

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE (last_name LIKE '%frank%')
OR (first_name LIKE '%frank%') 
OR (CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE '%frank%') 
OR (CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE '%frank%') 
AND deleted = 0 AND scholar = 0 ORDER BY `date_created` desc LIMIT 25
```

also remove the extra `$select =`. Your whole select should likly look something like:

```
//first line initializes the select object
//The select object will handle most quoting needs for you

$select = $this->select();

//I like to add expressions this way just to keep things easy to read and easy to edit
//you can string multiple statements together, but I find that harder to edit.

$select->where('last_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%');
$select->orWhere('first_name LIKE ?', '%'.$term.'%');
$select->orWhere("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%');
$select->orWhere("CONCAT(last_name,' ', first_name) LIKE ?", '%'.$term.'%');
$select->where("deleted = ?", 0);
$select->where("scholar = ?", 0);
$select->order('date_created DESC');
$select->limit(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
            // User List

$uname=$_POST['uname'];

echo $query = $user->select()->where('firstname LIKE ?', $uname.'%')->ORwhere('lastname LIKE ?', $_POST['lname'].'%')->ORwhere('emailid LIKE ?', $_POST['email'].'%');

$userlist = $user->fetchAll($query);
```