# sql: result be only data with a specific item_id

Tags: php, sql

how can, in this code,  do for the result be only data with a specific `item_id` like `item_id = 3`?

```
$articles = $dbRead->select()
             ->from('articles', array('article_id', 'name', 'item_id'))
             ->joinUsing('items', 'item_id', array('item_name'))
             ->order(array('updated  DESC'));
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? How would you apply `WHERE` clause to your query? I'm assuming you have a method called `where`? Can you show us the definition of that?

Comment: Yes, Zend and is for Zend_Paginator , but I'm very very Rookie and the WHERE dont work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       $articles = $dbRead->select()
     ->from('articles', array('article_id', 'name', 'item_id'))
     ->joinUsing('items', 'item_id', array('item_name'))->where("items.item_id = 3")
     ->order(array('updated  DESC'));
```

Comment: Nop:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'item_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: USE ->where("items.item_id = 3")

Comment: nothing: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3a' in 'where clause'

Comment: Pls refer below links
http://www.jaapsblog.nl/blog/view/29/zf2-writing-advanced-mysql-where-clauses.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061893/zend-framework-sql-select-query-construction-where-clause